# SQL Server 2005, how to copy a Database Diagram to another server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, ssms

Is there a way to copy a SQL Server Database Diagram to another server?

I found [this](http://nestas.blogspot.com/2008/07/move-database-diagrams-in-sql-server.html) and modified it sightly to copy only one diagram:

```
INSERT INTO dbB.dbo.sysdiagrams 
SELECT [name],[principal_id],[version],[definition]
FROM dbA.dbo.sysdiagrams
Where name = 'MyDiagramName'
```

But I need to copy it to another Server (Development to Production).

I don't want to create a linked server to do this. (***Updated explanation***) The reason behind that is that I want to include the diagram in a upgrade script. I made changes to the database to support a new version (new tables, etc) and I want the diagram be be part of the upgrade script. so it's best if i could put that in a SQL script. If a got a separated file to manually import afterward, it could do the job, but it not the best.

So i need to 'save' the diagram definition to a file somehow to restore it on the other server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found [this solution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ScriptDiagram2005.aspx).

In this article, There's the code to create the Stored Procedure that generate a SQL Server Script to recreate the diagrams. So you just save the output of the Stored Procedure in a .SQL file and run it on the other server.

The problem is to convert Varbinary To a String (Varchar) in Hex in order to be able use it in a insert/update query. But it's well explained in the link...

Answer (score 2):

First : Create one Link Server From `Source Server` inside `Destination Server`.

For create `Link Server` use [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402197/how-to-create-the-linked-server-for-sql-server-2008-where-we-have-the-database-f)

Second : Use This

```
USE DestinationDatabase

DELETE  sysDiagrams
WHERE   name IN ( SELECT    name
              FROM      <LinkServerName>.SourceDatabase.dbo.sysDiagrams )

SET IDENTITY_INSERT sysDiagrams ON

INSERT  sysDiagrams
    ( name ,
      principal_id ,
      diagram_id ,
      version ,
      definition
    )
    SELECT  name ,
            principal_id ,
            diagram_id ,
            version ,
            definition
    FROM    <LinkServerName>.SourceDatabase.dbo.sysDiagrams

SET IDENTITY_INSERT sysDiagrams OFF
```

Comment: I specified in the question I don't want to use a link server because the diagram need to be included in an upgrade script. Thanks anyway.

Comment: use Open DataSource against Link Server .

Comment: You just don't get it. What if the destination server don't "see" the source server?

Comment: ok. this link maybe help you : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43076/Backup-SQL-Diagrams-In-Less-Than-5-Minutes

Comment: I thinks you need backup scripts for all diagram from source database and then you can run this back up without consider existence source database on destination database.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following with success.

1. Create a temporary table in the source base to copy the binary diagram definition(s) to a table that you can generate a script from *(because SysDiagrams isn't an option in Generate Scripts wizard)* :

```sql
    CREATE TABLE CopySysDiagrams (
        name NvarChar(200), principal_id INT, diagram_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
        version INT, [definition] varBinary(MAX) )
    
    INSERT INTO CopySysDiagrams SELECT * from sysdiagrams   
        -- optional WHERE clause if you only need one diagram
```

2. Use Tasks... Generate Scripts... and the script it produces will contain the binary definitions of the diagram(s) in 0x format
3. Use a script like the following in the target base *(where 19 in this case is first free ID because there were 18 before)*, copying the binary data 0x string into here:

```sql
    SET identity_insert sysDiagrams ON

    INSERT sysDiagrams (name, principal_id, diagram_id, version, definition) 
        VALUES  ('Your Diagram Name', 1, 19, 1, 
                    0xTHEBINARYDATA
                 )

    SET identity_insert sysDiagrams OFF
```

Answer (score -1):

This tutorial/example will explain it

http://www.sharpdeveloper.net/content/archive/2008/04/19/copy-a-database-diagram-to-another-database.aspx

Comment: This use a 'temporary table'. that don't work for the another Server scenario.

Comment: Have you ever used a link server?

Comment: Yes, but I want to do it without, that's part of the question.