# Restore stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 R2 and I created this stored procedure for restoring databases:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_DBRestore]
@DBName nvarchar(60)
,@BackName nvarchar(120)
,@OutMessage nvarchar(4000) output
--,
--@DataName varchar(60),
--@DataFileName varchar(120),
--@LogName varchar(60),
--@LogFileName varchar(120)
AS

BEGIN TRY
    USE [master]

    ALTER DATABASE @DBName SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    RESTORE DATABASE @DBName FROM
        DISK = @BackName WITH
        FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD, 
        REPLACE,
        PASSWORD = 'TEST'
    SET @OutMessage = 'OK';
    ALTER DATABASE @DBName SET  MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    ALTER DATABASE @DBName SET  MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

    INSERT [dbo].[ErrorLog]
  (
   [UserName], 
   [ErrorNumber], 
   [ErrorSeverity], 
   [ErrorState], 
   [ErrorProcedure], 
   [ErrorLine], 
   [ErrorMessage] 
   )
   VALUES(
          CONVERT(sysname, CURRENT_USER), 
          ERROR_NUMBER(),
          ERROR_SEVERITY(),
          ERROR_STATE(),
          ERROR_PROCEDURE(),
          ERROR_LINE(),
          ERROR_MESSAGE()

         )
END CATCH
```

When I execute code I see this error :

> a USE database statement is not allowed in a procedure, function or
>   trigger.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: **Don't** have a `USE ...` in your stored procedure..... that's really the **only** solution. Why do you need this inside a stored procedure? Can't you just keep it as a standalone query? (that's what I do)

Comment: And even if you don't have that `USE master` in your database - this `ALTER DATABASE @DBName` won't work either, since you cannot specify the database name as a parameter .....

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in that way - you basically have two options:

1. stick to a stored procedure, but in that case, you have to use dynamic SQL. Your stored procedure creates a string of SQL statements, which allows it to use `USE master` and it allows it to dynamically set the database name etc., and then it executes that SQL statement using `sp_executesql @sqlRestoreStatement`. If you want to check this out, you **MUST** be all means read (and understand) Erland Sommarskog's seminal article [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)
2. you can use a regular SQL script, possibly with SQLCMD placeholders (if you have `SQLCMD mode` enabled in your SQL Server Management Studio) and execute the restore from a regular script (which you can put into your own template folder, for instance). In that case, you'd have something like:

   ```
   :setvar dbname YourDatabaseNameHere

   DECLARE @FileName NVARCHAR(255)
   SET @FileName = N'D:\YourBackupDirectory\SomeDatabase.bak' 

   RESTORE DATABASE [$(dbname)]
   FROM DISK = @FileName
   WITH FILE = 1,  
   MOVE N'YourDatabase_Data' TO N'D:\MSSQL\Data\$(dbname).mdf',  
   MOVE N'YourDatbase_Log' TO N'D:\MSSQL\Data\$(dbname)_Log.ldf',  
   NOUNLOAD, REPLACE,  
   STATS = 2
   GO
   ```

   With this setup, you can easily use the SQL script as a template and restore any kind of database using it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the USE statement. Best is to remove Use statement and create / Alter this sp on master database itself.

If you want to take a backup execute this SP from master DB. I can not see any other way out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a linked server and have that referenced in your stored procedure. 
For example. LinkedServer.database.[dbo].StoredProcedure

Check out this
[How to create the linked server for SQL Server 2008 where we have the database from 2000 and 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402197/how-to-create-the-linked-server-for-sql-server-2008-where-we-have-the-database-f)