# SQL Server: connect to another instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a question for SQL Server. I have a stored procedure which should access another SQL Server to copy the data to another server.

Is this possible? If yes: how can I do this?

I cannot find some sample.

I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I think this could work with linked servers. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Linked Server Example Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091960/sql-server-linked-server-example-query) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402197/how-to-create-the-linked-server-for-sql-server-2008-where-we-have-the-database-f

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example...

Connect to the first server, and run this script

```
CREATE DATABASE [DatabaseA];
GO
CREATE TABLE [DatabaseA].[dbo].[TableA] (Id int, ValueA varchar(10));
INSERT INTO [DatabaseA].[dbo].[TableA] VALUES(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');
```

Then connect to the second server, and run this

```
CREATE DATABASE [DatabaseB];
GO
CREATE TABLE [DatabaseB].dbo.[TableB] (Id int, ValueB varchar(10));
INSERT INTO [DatabaseB].dbo.[TableB] VALUES(1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'B');
```

In the connection to the first server, we create a link to the second like this

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'LINKTOB'
    ,@srvproduct=N'B'
    ,@provider=N'SQLOLEDB'
    ,@datasrc=N'<NAME OF SERVER CONTAINING DatabaseB>';
```

Note that you need to change the value of **@datasrc** to suit your environment.

Now we can on the first server run a query like this, using data from the two separate servers in the same query

```
SELECT
    a.Id
    ,a.ValueA
    ,b.ValueB
FROM
    [DatabaseA].[dbo].[TableA] AS a
    INNER JOIN [LINKTOB].[DatabaseB].[dbo].[TableB] AS b ON a.Id = b.Id
```

The result should look like this

[image: Screenshot of query result]

If both servers are in the same domain with the same security settings, everything should work without any further change. If not, take a look in **Management Studio** under **Server Objects - Linked Servers - LINKTOB**. Open properties for **LINKTOB** and have a look at the **Security**-tab.

Answer (score 1):

TheQ's answer should be your first option.

For ad-hoc MSSQL to MSSQL connection requirements, [OpenDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) is a good option.
For example, to query an external table:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI',
'Data Source=London\Payroll;Integrated Security=SSPI')
.AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee
```