# Copy columns and its data from a table in one database to another table in a different server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables, TABLE1 with columns *col1, col2, col3, col4* and *col5* in a database on server1. I have TABLE2 with the same columns and almost same data as TABLE1 excluding columns *col2* and *col5* in a database on server2. TABLE2 has the same data in *col1, col3 and col4* as TABLE1. Now I know I can just create a new table and use the import/export feature of sql-server. But this would not be feasible if the tables had tons of data and more columns.

So my question is there any way to insert data in *col2* and *col5* to TABLE2 through any other means? If this is possible I would like to make sure the data that is being inserted is *col2* and *col5* in TABLE2 matches to that of TABLE1 meaning if I have *col1* with data lets say 5 and *col2* has data xyz, would like this data to be inserted at this row. (FYI col1 is the primary key on both tables).

Both servers are sql server 2008r2.

Comment: Why don't you just add new columns `col2` and `col5` into `table2` on `server2` and insert all at the same time?  Alternatively, if you've imported the data before adding the columns, then you can just join on your PK and update the newly added columns.

Comment: Right, I can do that between 2 tables on the same database in the same server. How would I do it when moving those data to a different server? Would I have to do anything different? I am quite new to sql servers.

Comment: You'll need to create a linked server.  Details are in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the two SQL servers are on the same network, make a linked server on server2.

[How to create the linked server for SQL Server 2008 where we have the database from 2000 and 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402197/how-to-create-the-linked-server-for-sql-server-2008-where-we-have-the-database-f)

You may need to do an IDENTITY INSERT should you wish to keep the Id columns the same.

[How to turn IDENTITY_INSERT on and off using SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063501/how-to-turn-identity-insert-on-and-off-using-sql-server-2008)

You would be able to write an INSERT statement along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO [server2].[database1].[table1] ( col1, col3, col5 )
SELECT col1, col3, col5 FROM [server1].[database1].[table1]
```

If you don't want to introduce duplicate keys, use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS col1 IN ( ... )`.

If you don't want to introduce duplicate rows, use a `EXCEPT` statement.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up joining it on col1 after I setup the linked server.