# SQL Agent Job dependency between two Servers

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I've two SQL Agent jobs in two different Servers (D01->preload & s01->dwload).

My requirement is to run dwload job in s01 only after preload job in D01 is successfully completed.

preload job runs at 1:00AM and finishes at 7:00AM.

As of now, I've scheduled dwload to run at 8:00AM to avoid conflicts and disable it manually if preload fails for some reason.

**My question:** How do I create dependency between dwload and preload as they belong to different servers.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a linked server in one of the instances. Here are a couple of links on how to set that up.

[How to Create a Linked Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx)

[StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402197/how-to-create-the-linked-server-for-sql-server-2008-where-we-have-the-database-f)

[Calling Linked Server In Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091960/sql-server-linked-server-example-query)

Once you have the linked server set up, you could create one job for both of them. Preload would be step 1 of the job and dwload would be step 2.

Comment: Both preload and dwload were SSIS packages. However, I could pull both tasks in one job after creating linked server. Thank you.