# Export table data from one SQL Server to another another table sitting on different server

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to fetch the data from one database table on another server and insert in to another database table sitting on a different server....I can't to do this.Is it possible using SQL statement or do I need a tool?

Comment: You can do this, have you looked into [Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine)?

Comment: No will the allow me to get all table rows and some of the columns?

Comment: Yes, it will allow you to run almost any query between the SQL servers.

Comment: If it is a once off you could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/welcome-to-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard    otherwise if you need to run sql queries use linked Servers as Jacob said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a linked server on the instance that you are importing data into. You will need to link the server that you are exporting data from. Here are a couple of links on how to set that up.

[How to Create a Linked Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx)

[StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402197/how-to-create-the-linked-server-for-sql-server-2008-where-we-have-the-database-f)

[Calling Linked Server In Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091960/sql-server-linked-server-example-query)

Once you have the linked server set up, you could do this:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable --table you are importing data into
SELECT *
FROM [server].[database].[schema].[table] --server you are exporting data from
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man the the links were valuable, I managed to sort my issue