# Turn existing server into linked server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am using two SQL 2012 servers and am trying to link them together so I can import data between the two.  I have read online that the way to do this is to utilize one as a linked server that is linked to the other.  However, what I see online is that you have to create a linked server.  Neither server that I am utilizing are linked already.  Is there a way to make one of the servers linked so that I can send data from it to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of links on how to set that up.

[How to Create a Linked Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx)

[StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402197/how-to-create-the-linked-server-for-sql-server-2008-where-we-have-the-database-f)

[Calling Linked Server In Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091960/sql-server-linked-server-example-query)

Once you have the linked server set up, you could do this:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable --table you are importing data into
SELECT *
FROM [server].[database].[schema].[table] --server you are exporting data from
```