# Update table on one sql server based on data from a table on another SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I have two SQL Server instances (`LocalDb` and `LiveDb`) using two different connection strings. I currently use C#'s `SqlBulkCopy` to transfer master tables to from the `Livedb` to my `localDb`. This works fine and is very fast.

However, I need to `UPDATE` tables on my `LiveDb` based on a query of records from my `LocalDB`. Is there an example of doing this in a C# Windows application?

Comment: Is LiveDB production database?

Comment: Yes.   My app is a time clock, check in/check out that I am writing.  The program runs fully on the local instance of sql.  It writes check in records to the live production db every 30 seconds.  My issue is how to update a field on the live db when a local db check out happens?

Comment: A little more info.   The record I need to update on live db is based on the local db's record

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to set up a linked server... [here's a good note on that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402764/6167855)

Once you do that, it will be something like this (run this using your `LiveDb` connection)

```
update l
   set l.someColumn = lo.someColumn
from
   TableName l                      --live db here...
inner join
   LocalDb.dbo.TableName lo on      --linked server
   lo.TableNameID = l.TableNameID   --or what ever join condition
```

Or, if you were doing some sort of staging process... perhaps something like this.

```
select
   ...
into #myTempTable          --often faster to stage data when pulling from linked server
from 
   LocalDb.dbo.TableName   --linked server

update l
   ...
TableName l                      --live db here...   
etc...
```