# how to sum from two tables on two computers using SQL Server Management Studio 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two computers located at two stores. One is with the ip 192.168.10.100, another is with the ip 192.68.10.200. Both computers has database have database: StoreInformation. Both databases have table: Inventory. Both tables have ItemNum, ItemDescription, and Quantity.
I want to sum the total of quantity for each individual items on both tables.
Eg.
Store1->StoreInformation->Inventory

```
ItemNum ItemDescription Quantity
000001  Apple           10
000002  Pear            15
```

Store2->StoreInformation->Inventory

```
ItemNum ItemDescription Quantity
000001  Apple           8
000002  Pear            21
```

I want to result to show:

```
ItemNum ItemDescription Quantity
000001  Apple           18
000002  Pear            36
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: I just have the thought of using query. Currently I export the tables to excel and use excel formula to get the result.

Comment: create a linked server and join the two tables

Comment: Here's an [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402197/how-to-create-the-linked-server-for-sql-server-2008-where-we-have-the-database-f) regarding linked servers in SQL Server 2008. Once they're linked you'll be able to link/union tables in both databases.

Comment: Thank you very much. Link server works great. It solves my problem.