# How to setup linked server in Sql server to contained database on other Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

If it is possible I would like to set up a linked server

from my Sql server 2014 SP2 
to a contained database on another Sql Server

I have a secure tunnel server:port  that is all setup

Is this possible and how do I set this up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create the linked server for SQL Server 2008 where we have the database from 2000 and 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402197/how-to-create-the-linked-server-for-sql-server-2008-where-we-have-the-database-f)

Comment: The fact that your remote database is contained should have no bearing on accessing it. Linked servers, as the name imply, function on the server level, not the database level. You will need to ensure authorization works across the link, but that is true for non-contained DBs as well. Contained DBs just have their own set of (SQL) accounts if you're not using integrated authentication.